# How to search through object with variable? -- javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

My problem is the following:

```
var alphabet = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f: 6, g: 7, h: 8, i: 9, j: 10, k: 11, l: 12, m: 13, n: 14, o: 15, p: 16, q: 17, r: 18, s: 19, t: 20, u: 21, v: 22, w: 23, x: 24, y: 25, z: 26 };

var chr = 'a'
```

But when I try to do the following:
`var chr2 = alphabet.chr` it returns `(object Object)`

Sorry if this is a simple question, I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: use `alphabet[chr]` ... also *it returns (object Object)* - this is extremely surprising .. that should be `undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX it's undefined, that is correct.

Comment: yes, I know I'm correct :p

Comment: Could you let me know where the original question is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets